# Steam API - how to decode location codes

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, geocoding, steam

Good day! 
Users of our site signups by steam OpenId, and when app gets their person info in JSON. An information about user location is provided as set of ISO(?) codes, like this: "loccountrycode": "RU", "locstatecode": "47", "loccityid": 41795. Steam API is wery badly documented, so i can't find any method to decode this to a string. Is there a some method in Steam API to do this, and if not, are there any convinient web-api's to do this? We use nodejs.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, just wanted to share. https://github.com/Holek/steam-friends-countries

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).